# How to build both an html and json api on sails.js

Tags: javascript, json, sails.js

There is excellent documentation and screencasts (Sailscasts) on how to make either a JSON API or an HTML (EJS) templated app using Sails.js, but is there a way to create a JSON API and an HTML webapp simultaneously. In rails this is done using either respond_to do |format| block or (in a more scalable fashion) with namespaced, versioned api routes and controllers.

http://www.emilsoman.com/blog/2013/05/18/building-a-tested/

is there something similar in sails.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajbraus, I would recommend using the wantsJSON method instead. For example:

```
'/contentNegotiation': function(req, res) {

    // req.wantsJSON
    // https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/request/index.js#L282

    if (req.wantsJSON) {
        res.json(user);
    } else {
        res.redirect('/user');;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what determines if wantsJSON will be true? Is it the format of the request? So, if the request comes in as '/contentNegotiation.json' -> wantsJSON will be true?

Answer (score 1):

One way to to do this is to build your own sailsy respond_to do |format| block

```
  if(req.isJson) {
    res.json(user); 
  }
  else {
    res.redirect('/user');  
  }
```

You could also add an req.isAjax response as well if you like. Used here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Di50_eHqI7I

But this is not namespaced routes and is therefore not as scalable and extensible as I'd like.